# Is there an algebraic relationship equating these inner products?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector inner product $a^\intercal b$. The vector $a$ is constructed from the element-wise product of two other vectors $c$ and $d$. Hence, $a^\intercal b = (c \odot d)^\intercal b$.

My question is, is there some algebraic expression which relates the inner product $a^\intercal b$ to the inner products $c^\intercal b$ and $d^\intercal b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and this is simple to show. Consider
\begin{align*}
b &= (1, -1, 1) \\
c_1 &= (1, 1, 0) \\
d_1 &= (1, 1, 1) \\
c_2 &= (-2, -2, 0) \\
d_2 &= (3, 1, -1).
\end{align*}
Note that $c_1 \cdot b = c_2 \cdot b = 0$ and $d_1 \cdot b = d_2 \cdot b = 1$. On the other hand, we have $c_1 \odot d_1 = (1, 1, 0)$ and $c_2 \odot d_2 = (-6, -2, 0)$, and so
\begin{align*}
(c_1 \odot d_1) \cdot b &= 0 \\
(c_2 \odot d_2) \cdot b &= -4.
\end{align*}
If there were a function to take $c \cdot b$ and $d \cdot b$ to the value of $(c \odot d) \cdot b$, then we would expect that $(c_1 \odot d_1) \cdot b =
(c_2 \odot d_2) \cdot b$, which is not the case.